# js привязка клавиши

Tags: javascript, html, html5, button

написал простенькую программу для арифметических вычислений ,как привязать клавишу Enter к моему button , чтобы при нажатии срабатывала кнопка вычислить

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Ввод click'));

document.addEventListener('keyup', (ev) => {
  if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log('Ввод enter');
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```